# UIAutomator on android lower than 4.3

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

Is it possible to use UIautomator on api < 18?
Main purpose of auto-tests is regression testing and devices with android 4.1, 4.2 should also be tested.
Maybe UIautomator library versions lower than 2.0 can be used, but i cant find any info about previous versions.

Comment: Uiauomator only works on API Level 16 or greater. You cannot use Uiautomator for API Level < 16.

Answer (score 9):

Add an androidTest specific AndroidManifest.xml to your project that contains the following:

```
<manifest
    package="${applicationId}.test"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18"/>
</manifest>
```

This will get merged with your default AndroidManifest.xml and allow you to keep your minSDK for your production app, and allow you to test using UIAutomator.

Comment: Somehow this is keep giving me errors during syncing my project in Android Studio. But build the project is going fine. Any idea?

Comment: @PeterFortuin Can you post the errors and provide the version of Android Studio and the gradle plugin that you are using?

Comment: It worked for me. You need to add the `AndroidManifest.xml` inside the path `/app/src/androidTest/`

Comment: @AndréLuizReis this comment saved my life cheers

Answer (score 0):

UIAutomator works only with Android 4.1+. (http://uiautomator.blogspot.com/2013/11/what-is-ui-automator.html)

If you want to test UI on lower versions of Android e.g. 2.2, please use Espresso (is developed by Google and it supports all Android versions).
link to espresso: https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso

Comment: that's it, 4.1+ is ok for me, the problem is that release UIAutomator version v2.1.1 Dependencies and Prerequisites  are **Android 4.3 (API level 18) or higher**

Where can i get pre-release version for android 4.1+?

Comment: UIAutomator v2 is significantly better that the previous version. Im running into the same problem. I have a min api target set to 16, but i want to run UI automator tests with previously existing Espresso tests, since some of test flow requires interaction outside the app itself. At the moment i have to set the min API to 18 to run the test. If anyone has a solution it would be nice :)

Comment: @Adr3nl check out my answer to this question to see if it works for you.